# Android: How to run widget in another task?

Tags: android, widget, task

I implemented some app. Besides my app  has some kind of widget.  This Widget just starts PlayStore. My problem is, that if widget is started and I press Home-Button and the open my app (not widget), I see not the first Activity of my app (main Activity), but the Activity from my widget. I found one possibility that I can use. For that I need to set main Activity of my app:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

It works, but I used also for starting of PlayStore `startActivityForResult()` . And it doesn´t work then because:

> A "singleInstance" activity, on the other hand, permits no other
>   activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task.
>   If it starts another activity, that activity is assigned to a
>   different task.

Have somebody an idea how can I solve that? I would be very thankful.

Comment: Get rid of `startActivityForResult()`. You cannot just decide to start activities that way -- they have to be specifically designed for use with `startActivityForResult()` and documented as such.

Comment: @CommonsWare Does it possible to block my app, while widget is running or something like that? For example that if user run widget, then press home button and then runs my app it show alert message oer something like that?